# Пробелы в textarea

Tags: php, html, css

Использую поле <[textarea](http://htmlbook.ru/html/textarea)> для считывания данных из БД. Код такой:

```
<textarea style="min-height:2em;width:70%; margin-left: 15%; text-align: center; " name="title" id="title">
             <?php $post = mysqli_query($mydata, "SELECT title FROM article WHERE id=3");
             $post_array = $post->fetch_assoc();
             $new_title=implode($post_array);
             print_r ($new_title);
             ?>
         </textarea>
```

При этом в тексте, который отображается в поле **textarea**, появляются пробелы перед текстом и после. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как от этого избавиться? ([trim](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php) не помагает).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чему здесь удивляться, если ты сам эти пробелы и пишешь?

```
<textarea style="min-height:2em;width:70%; margin-left: 15%; text-align: center; " name="title" id="title">
         <?php $post = mysqli_query($mydata, "SELECT title FROM article WHERE id=3");
^^^^^^^^^ пробел
         $post_array = $post->fetch_assoc();
         $new_title=implode($post_array);
         print_r ($new_title);
         ?>
     </textarea>
^^^^^ пробел
```

но вообще такой код - это ад.
Данные сначала получают, и только потом начинают вывод.

```
<?php 
$row = $mydata->query("SELECT title FROM article WHERE id=3")->fetch_assoc();
$title = $row['title'];
?>
<textarea class="myclass" name="title" id="title"><?=$title?></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо. В дальнейшем про данные получают-выводят учту.

Answer (score 1):

Удалите переносы строки вот так:

```
<textarea style="min-height:2em;width:70%; margin-left: 15%; text-align: center; " name="title" id="title"><?php $post = mysqli_query($mydata, "SELECT title FROM article WHERE id=3");
             $post_array = $post->fetch_assoc();
             $new_title=implode($post_array);
             print_r ($new_title);
             ?></textarea>
```

Ваш редактор добавляет эти пробелы между открывающими тегами текстареа и php, и закрывающими соответственно.

Еще замечу, разделяйте логику (например получение данных в данном случае) и отображение. Почитайте про [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), разберитесь с этим как следует, чтобы сразу привыкать делать правильно. Очень неправильно делать запросы во время формирования (вывода) html-кода страницы.

Comment: Спасибо. Почитаю.

Answer (score 1):

У меня тоже появлялись пробелы после отправки формы, причина была в том, что между открывающим и закрывающим тегом в коде html были пробелы между открывающим и закрывающим тегом textarea, сомкнул теги и пробелы исчезли.